# How can I filter by ID and by name and city in react native with redux?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

If I fetch this array of restos with redux:

```
[{
res_id: Int,
res_name: String,
res_category: String,
res_category_id: Int,
city_id: Int
}]
```

My action looks something like this:

```
export const getrestos = () => {

        const resData = await response.json();

        dispatch({
            type: GET_RESTOS,
            payload: resData
        });
    };
};

export const setFilters = filterSettings => {
    console.log(filterSettings);
    return { type: SET_FILTERS, filters: filterSettings };
};
```

And this is my reducer:

```
import { GET_RESTOS, SET_FILTERS } from '../actions/restos';

const initialState = {
    restoList: [],
    filteredRestos: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_RESTOS:
            return {
                restoList: action.payload
            }
        case SET_FILTERS:
            const appliedFilters = action.filters;
            const updatedFilteredRestos = state.restoList.filter(resto => {
                if (appliedFilters.cityID || resto.city_id) {
                    resto => resto.city_id.indexOf(cityID) >= 0
                    return { ...state, filteredRestos: updatedFilteredRestos };
                }
            });
            return { ...state, filteredRestos: updatedFilteredRestos };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I have touchable categorys in a page, and when i touch one i want to fetch the corresponding restos for that category and show them in a flatlist. Apart from that i want to have a search bar that when I type I want to show restos by res_name and/or by res_category.

Ive tried to create selectors, but I dont understand how, i dont need an specific approach, but the most clean or efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance if anyone can give me a hint or solution!

**EDIT**

The problem is im getting undefined in updatedFilteredRestos.

Comment: Try to put here your solution (action creator, connecting state/action creator to the componet) and specify what you have problem with.

Comment: @lavor Ive updated my question, im getting undefined on updatedFilteredRestos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reducer`s should be clean, dumb and all they do should be returning objects.  This makes your components more testable and errors easier to catch.  In my opinion, this is a perfect use-case for `reselect`.  Here's a medium article: https://medium.com/@parkerdan/react-reselect-and-redux-b34017f8194c  But the true beauty of `reselect` is that it will `memoize` for you, i.e. if your states don't change, it uses a cached version of the data.

Anyway, you should clean up your `restoReducer` to something to this effect.

```
import { GET_RESTOS, SET_FILTERS } = "../actions/restos";

const initialState = {
    restoList: [],
    filteredRestos: []
};

const restoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_RESTOS:
            return { ...state, restoList: action.payload };
        case SET_FILTERS:
            return { ...state, filteredRestos: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Then write your filtered resto selector:

```
// ../selectors/restos
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

// First, get your redux states
const getRestos = (state) => state.restos.restoList;
const getFilteredRestos = (state) => state.restos.filteredRestos;

// Next, create selectors
export const getFilteredRestoList = createSelector(
    [getRestos, getFilteredRestos],
    (restoList, filteredRestos) => {
        // need to check for non-empty filters
        // if it is, simply return the unfiltered `restoList`
        if(!Array.isArray(filteredRestos) || !filteredRestos.length)
            return restoList || [];

        // If you do have valid filters, return filtered logic
        return restoList.filter(r => filteredRestos.some(f => f.cityID === r.city_id));
);
```

Then, use this selector in your components:

```
// ../components/my-app
import { getFilteredRestoList } from "../selectors/restos";

// hook it up to your `mapStateToProps` as you would a normal state
// except this time, it's a special selector
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    restoList: state.restos.restoList,
    filteredRestos: state.restos.filteredRestos,
    filteredRestoList: getFilteredRestoList(state) //<-- this is your selector
}
```

Then inside your component, just reference it:  `this.props.filteredRestoList`.